# FLUTTER: How to set auto font size in TextSpan

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement that text with divider in between lines:
[Smart City Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGf7P.png)

Do you guys have any ideas how can I implement that in flutter? I tried few things but it is kind of a challenge for me, because I am beginner. Divider line have to be long as text above and under line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a screen using [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package.
Using AutoSizeText and AutoSizeText.rich widget in that package,
and set a maxLines option to 1 and set font size big.
Because we set maxLines to 1, although set font size big, text will not be overflowed screen.
[image]

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 30),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          AutoSizeText(
            'Smart City',
            maxLines: 1,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 100,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          Divider(color: Colors.black),
          AutoSizeText.rich(
            TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'Advanced',
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: ' urban',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: ' lighting solution',
                ),
              ],
            ),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
            maxLines: 1,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for :)